# Disk not readable message when using

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, error

If I try to use either of the two usb ports on my macbook pro, I get the following message "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." and I don't have a disk inserted anywhere... I have the option to eject or ignore the message, and either option does not solve the problem. Can't use the usb ports without getting this message.

Comment: Does this persist through a restart? If so, if you open Disk Utility, are there any unexpected entries in the volume list on the left?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not clear what you put into those USB ports. Memory sticks appear to the system as a disk, so the message you quoted might be caused by a memory stick that had been formatted in a file system your Mac does not know (possibly from a Linux computer?).

If you want to widen your possibilities, you might consider installing [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io). But I would appreciate if you first clarify what you mean by "use either of the two usb ports".